# When did I set the administrator password for windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, passwords

I've just installed a windows 7 professional x64 [on my netbook], and started a program installer as a normal user (**edit:** whose account *type* is admin), that should have been started as administrator.

Thus windows gave me the choice to run this application as Administrator or as a normal user, and prompted for the admin password.

Now I do not recall setting any Administrator password during installation.

- Does the Administrator user have a password? How can I find out that password?
- Do I need to reset its password? How?
- When was this user created? Why did I haven't noticed?
- Does the Administrator user[1] impose a security risk if I am unaware of its existence?

+1

- Does it have anything to do with me not formatting a previous 7 installation?[2] The setup told me it will be renamed to "windows.old" and that I cannot start it any more.

---

[1]:  of a default installation naively executed by me "next-next-finish" style

[2]: I didn't want to format the drive as setup suggested that the manufacturer may have copied files to it that are important. It sounded reasonable but I couldn't check during installation so I skipped formatting.

Comment: Does it work if you enter your user (whose account is type admin) password as the admin password? It might be asking not for the password of the "administrator" account, but the password of the account which is trying to execute the program, which also must be an administrator account.

Comment: It's a "Run as" dialog. While it's asking for the password for "Administrator", I can change the username, too. It works if I run as with my original "admin-type" user.
On the other hand, the password for "Administrator" and how such user even exists is still an unknown area this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your windows 7 default administrator account is set to disabled by default and doesn't have a password unless your computer was set up by a system admin(i.e a work laptop), if it asks for an admin account your account should be set as an admin privileged account.

Check from windows user accounts control pannel, if it is just put your user name and password into the password prompt box on the installer.

Comment: Does "doesn't have a password" means that if I enable the account (and don't set a password), anyone could get full control of my system? Perhaps remotely?

Comment: No, to log into Windows Remotely -
No-1 Would have to have Remote Access Enabled
No-2 You can only access Remotly with a user that has a password.